# Moving log plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm

I wonder how could I shift my log plot (log y's and linear x's)? What operations should I use on my data sets to preserve shape of the plot, but to move it around (along y axis, up/down so to say)?

I am using python 3.7.6 and matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

testY=[8, 9, 11, 11, 12, 101, 120, 89, 92, 102]
testX=np.linspace(1,10,10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,figsize=(15, 9))
plt.yscale(value="log")
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(1, 2000)
ax.plot(testX, testY)
```

This produces very simple data sets, in this form I'd like to i.e move the plot up on the Y axis. What transform should I use on my testY to achieve this? Simple addition or multiplication doesn't seem to solve the problem.
My problem is that I have to visualize multiple normalized spectra with single XY plane. My Y's are flux values in log (or symlog) scale, and X are corresponding wavelengths (linear). The problem is that all this spectra obviously overlap and whole plot becomes a mess. So I'd like to just move them apart but also preserve their shapes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with a sample of your data and code for what you've already tried, as well as a description of what is wrong with your current effort, so that we can understand what it is you're trying to do and how to help

Comment: Ok, sorry. I didn't think it'll be needed with this kind of 'math' question.

Answer (score 1):

To shift the plot upwards, you have to *multiply* all the y values by a constant c. Conversely, to shift the plot downwards by the same amount, you have to *divide* all the y values by the same c.

For example (casting `testY` to a NumPy array for easy element-wise operations):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

testY = [8, 9, 11, 11, 12, 101, 120, 89, 92, 102]
testX = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 9))
plt.yscale(value="log")
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(1, 2000)
ax.plot(testX, testY)


# new code starts here

testY = np.array(testY)

Y_shifted_up = testY * 5
Y_shifted_down = testY / 5

ax.plot(testX, Y_shifted_up)
ax.plot(testX, Y_shifted_down)
```

[image: log-plot]

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that while trying with multiplication some weird scaling was on and so apparent change of shape was due to different range on y axis and not because of method itself.